# why constructor of abstract class calling first

Tags: java

**Please check the code

why constructor of abstract class calling first**

```
abstract class car
{
   car()           //creating a constructor for abstact class
     {
       System.out.println("four");
      }
abstract String getText();
}
```

adding subclass

```
public class abc extends car
{

String getText()      //override the getText Method
     {
        return "Hello from JSP!";
      }
```

static block

```
static
{
    System.out.println("Hello");
}
```

//blank blok

```
{
    System.out.println("two");
}
```

constructor for abc

```
abc()
{
    super();
    System.out.println("three");
}
```

//main method

```
public static void main(String []args)
{
    abc a = new abc();
    System.out.println("one");
}
}
```

thanks

Comment: Good programming practice - First letter of a class name must be in *Caps*.

Answer (score 1):

Superclass constructor is always called first before the subclass constructor. There is no problem in that and it is the standard behavior. Also note that it is perfectly valid for an abstract class to have constructor.